# Disposing a PublishSubject object in RxJava | Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, rx-java, dispose

While using PublishSubject instead of Observables in Java, during profiling I get memory leaks because of these. I do not see any associated disposable from the same .

Will invoking the onComplete() on the subject dispose it and resolve the issue?

What else can we do to resolve the memory leaks?

Any ideas?

Comment: what about just using a composite disposable and clearing it.

Comment: [history]: You are using disposable then there's nothing much, you can try calling onComplete() on subject

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation is always to try use Observables instead of Subjects; however, when it is necessary to use Subjects, you can unsubscribe manually using the **CompositeDisposable** component or through *lifecycle hook* like so:

```
    public class TakeSubscriptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String TAG = "TakeSubscriptionsActivity";
    private Subject<Boolean> cancel = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_subscriptions);

        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .takeUntil(cancel)
                .subscribe(element -> Log.d(TAG, "" + element));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cancel.onNext(true);
        cancel.onComplete();
    }
}
```